# Wordpress Plugin Custom Post Type Archive Template results in other pages not displaying

Tags: wordpress

This is the code I am using to call my archive template, now the knowledgebase section works, the forums work, but all other pages throughout the website are now blank.

```
function kb_archive_template_function($arhive_template){
    if(is_post_type_archive('knowledgebase')){
      $theme_files = array('/templates/archive-knowledgebase.php');
      $exists_in_theme = locate_template($theme_files, false);
      if($exists_in_theme == ''){
        return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/templates/archive-knowledgebase.php';
      }
      return $archive_template;
    }

  }
```

Comment: you got a typo in the first line: `$arhive_template`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code ,instead of your code

```
function get_custom_post_type_template( $archive_template ) {
     global $post;

     if ( is_post_type_archive ( 'knowledgebase' ) ) {
          $archive_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/templates/archive-knowledgebase.php';
     }
     return $archive_template;
}

add_filter( 'archive_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' ) ;
```

Try that, then let me know the result. Thanks